# Redis has no dump.rdb only a temp.rdb?

Tags: linux, git, redis

I think I may have messed something up with my redis config. Using nodeBB I am trying to share my .rdb file with git because I want to share the data in my local env and on my server.

In the process of looking for the .rdb file I do `redis-cli` then `CONFIG GET *` the result is the below output. Generally it gives me a path to the dump.rdb, but not in this case.

I am just testing thankfully but earlier the data went missing somehow. I cannot find it.

```
127.0.0.1:6379> CONFIG GET *
  1) "dbfilename"
  2) "temp.rdb"
  3) "requirepass"
  4) ""
  5) "masterauth"
  6) ""
  7) "unixsocket"
  8) ""
  9) "logfile"
 10) ""
 11) "pidfile"
 12) "/var/run/redis.pid"
 13) "maxmemory"
 14) "0"
 15) "maxmemory-samples"
 16) "5"
 17) "timeout"
 18) "0"
 19) "tcp-keepalive"
 20) "0"
 21) "auto-aof-rewrite-percentage"
 22) "100"
 23) "auto-aof-rewrite-min-size"
 24) "67108864"
 25) "hash-max-ziplist-entries"
 26) "512"
 27) "hash-max-ziplist-value"
 28) "64"
 29) "list-max-ziplist-entries"
 30) "512"
 31) "list-max-ziplist-value"
 32) "64"
 33) "set-max-intset-entries"
 34) "512"
 35) "zset-max-ziplist-entries"
 36) "128"
 37) "zset-max-ziplist-value"
 38) "64"
 39) "hll-sparse-max-bytes"
 40) "3000"
 41) "lua-time-limit"
 42) "5000"
 43) "slowlog-log-slower-than"
 44) "10000"
 45) "latency-monitor-threshold"
 46) "0"
 47) "slowlog-max-len"
 48) "128"
 49) "port"
 50) "6379"
 51) "tcp-backlog"
 52) "511"
 53) "databases"
 54) "16"
 55) "repl-ping-slave-period"
 56) "10"
 57) "repl-timeout"
 58) "60"
 59) "repl-backlog-size"
 60) "1048576"
 61) "repl-backlog-ttl"
 62) "3600"
 63) "maxclients"
 64) "4064"
 65) "watchdog-period"
 66) "0"
 67) "slave-priority"
 68) "100"
 69) "min-slaves-to-write"
 70) "0"
 71) "min-slaves-max-lag"
 72) "10"
 73) "hz"
 74) "10"
 75) "cluster-node-timeout"
 76) "15000"
 77) "cluster-migration-barrier"
 78) "1"
 79) "cluster-slave-validity-factor"
 80) "10"
 81) "repl-diskless-sync-delay"
 82) "5"
 83) "cluster-require-full-coverage"
 84) "yes"
 85) "no-appendfsync-on-rewrite"
 86) "no"
 87) "slave-serve-stale-data"
 88) "yes"
 89) "slave-read-only"
 90) "yes"
 91) "stop-writes-on-bgsave-error"
 92) "no"
 93) "daemonize"
 94) "no"
 95) "rdbcompression"
 96) "yes"
 97) "rdbchecksum"
 98) "yes"
 99) "activerehashing"
100) "yes"
101) "repl-disable-tcp-nodelay"
102) "no"
103) "repl-diskless-sync"
104) "no"
105) "aof-rewrite-incremental-fsync"
106) "yes"
107) "aof-load-truncated"
108) "yes"
109) "appendonly"
110) "no"
111) "dir"
112) ""
113) "maxmemory-policy"
114) "noeviction"
115) "appendfsync"
116) "everysec"
117) "save"
118) "3600 1 300 100 60 10000"
119) "loglevel"
120) "notice"
121) "client-output-buffer-limit"
122) "normal 0 0 0 slave 268435456 67108864 60 pubsub 33554432 8388608 60"
123) "unixsocketperm"
124) "0"
125) "slaveof"
126) ""
127) "notify-keyspace-events"
128) ""
129) "bind"
130) ""
```

Any ideas how to find the dump.rdb?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the `dir` config key is set to an empty string, you can probably find the dump.rdb in the directory that redis was started from. If you don't know what it is, on linux you can find it by doing `ls -l /proc/$(pidof redis-server)/cwd`.

Comment: This is the result `lrwxrwxrwx 1 mike mike 0 Mar 19 23:14 /proc/6391/cwd -> /redis_data (deleted)`

Comment: @MichaelJosephAubry well, that's problematic. You may not be able to access the file, then. How about doing a `config set dir` to a directory that actually exists, followed by a `bgsave` to make sure the DB is written out?

Comment: Ok cool very helpful. So going forward what should I consider? I actually am glad I was able to set the dir manually because thats what I needed.

Comment: @MichaelJosephAubry nothing, other than having a sensible `dir` in the config file.